# PDO Fetch Array like MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, mysqli

I know how to fetch a PDO array, but how do I collect data from it like you do with MySQLi's fetch_array?

For example,

**MySQLi**

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `ID`='1'");
$array = $query->fetch_array();
```

*Getting a result*

```
echo $array['bar'];
```

How would you do this with PDO? I understand you can do this:

**PDO**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `ID`='1'");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

*Getting the result*

```
echo $result['bar'];
```

> Does not return the same as MySQLi did

Am I doing something wrong, and is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Read `fetch_style` parameter http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

Comment: You have to understand, that while the `fetch_array()` iterates over the whole result set and returns one row at a time, `fetchAll()` returns the whole result set. Do this instead: `$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Something I remember from my PHP days that you may find useful is using `print_r()` and/or `var_dump()` to divine the often poorly-documented data structures PHP throws at you.

Comment: @tgies: Nothing is poorly-documented here. The first commenter's link points to a correct documentation.

Comment: @mark.sagikazar Not in this case, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fetchAll()` is *not* the same as `fetch_array()`.

You want `fetch()` to get *one* row, not `fetchAll()` which gets *ALL* rows.

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'm new to PDO as I want to ditch MySQL and MySQLi all together, as you can probably see. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 I'll add that you should be able to omit the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` because the default is to return an array that is indexed both associatively and numerically.

Comment: Is the `PDO::` before the `FETCH_*` absolutely necessary? And why? I believe in MySQLi you just need to parse in `FETCH_*`

Comment: `PDO` is the class name, and the `FETCH_*` thing is a constant.

Comment: @EthanWebster: `FETCH_ASSOC` is a constant of the `PDO` class.  `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is how you access it.  It's 100% necessary :)

Comment: But MySQLi is also a class, why doesn't that need to be `MYSQLI::FETCH_*` ?

Comment: `::` means static access. You use `->` (eg. `$query->`). That is object-context. Constants can be accessed statically in a class.